# Does tracking mean nothing but linking optical flow vectors?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tracking, opticalflow

If I find optical flow between successive frames of a video and link all the optical flow vectors, does this mean I have implemented tracking?
If yes is this the simple way of tracking?

Comment: yes and yes. But it is a very vulnerable way of tracking. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking defines a computer vision task with the goal to track a given object, region of interesset or point in consequtive images of a video sequence. A very simple method would be based on the motion vectors estimated by an optical flow estimation method. 
However, this would produce good results at very cooperative enviromental conditions. It would fail e.g. if the object get occluded. Recent state-of-the-art method are more robust and e.g. based on Kalman-Filter, Particel Filter or PHD filter technologies. This [Survey on Object Tracking](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6671560) or [Object tracking:A survey](http://www.ppgia.pucpr.br/~alceu/pdi/Video%20Segmentation%20and%20Tracking/Yilmaz.pdf)gives you an better overwiev of the challenges and solution of current object tracking methods.

Comment: The survey on Object Tracking you referred above redirected me to opencv docs. Did you refer to open cv docs or something else

Comment: Sorry copy-paste error I changed link. Or see here http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6671560